# Processing struts2 tags in freemarker templates

Tags: templates, process, struts2, tags, freemarker

I have a requirement to process freemarker ftl file on server side and return back the HTML to  the client. I would like to know if it is possible to process freemaker template having struts tags in it using template.process().

**Action class code:**

```
// Configuration created from struts2 freemarkermanager
FreemarkerManager freeMarkerManager = new FreemarkerManager();
Configuration config = freeMarkerManager.getConfiguration(context);

//Configuration without any specific settings.
Configuration config = new Configuration();
//Tried both nothing works.

Template template = config.getTemplate("TEMPLATE PATH");

Map<String, Object> inputMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
inputMap.put("document", document);

StringWriter output = new StringWriter();
template.process(inputMap, output);
```

**Freemarker template**:

```
<#assign s=JspTaglibs["/struts-tags"]>
    <table>
        <tr>
           <th><@s.text name="Document Name"/></th>
           <th><@s.text name="Description"/></th>
        </tr>
        <@s.iterator value="inspiration" status="status">
    <tr>
    <td class="nowrap"><@s.property value="properties.DOCUMENT_NAME"/></td>
    <td class="nowrap"><@s.property value="properties.DESCRIPTION"/></td>
    </tr>
        </@s.iterator>
    </table>
```

I have also added **struts-tags.tld** under web-inf folder.

**Exception**

freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: Expression JspTaglibs is undefined on line 1,

If I remove **<#assign s=JspTaglibs["/struts-tags"]>**

freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: Expression s is undefined on line 7

Comment: Obviously it's *possible*, because the FreeMarker result does it. JSP support needs more configuration; check out the source or the FM docs.

Comment: Is there any example of customizing FreeMarkerResult.

Comment: Why would you need to customize the FreeMarker result? You're not using a result. I don't understand what you're trying to do if you're returning the results of an FM template as part of an action, but not using the FM result, though.

Comment: I'm not returning FM template as a result. I want to process FM in struts action class and get HTML out of it.

Comment: And I'm saying to do that, and use JSP tags, you need to configure FM to be able to use the tags, set up a value stack and provide it to the FM context, etc. That's why I said to look at the FM result source to see what all is involved. I don't see any reason to use JSP tags inside an FM template if you're not using it as a result, though, just fill the context normally, and write the HTML yourself.

Comment: Maybe it's just that I don't know the FreeMarker integration of Struts, but... FreeMarker has its own directives for iteration, for inserting values, for if/else, etc. If you still have to use Struts JSP tags instead of them, then what's the point of using FreeMarker instead of JSP? Because then FreeMarker will be as verbose as JSP, plus you will have all sort of tricky situations because its JSP support is, well, not the real thing.

Comment: Thanks Dave & ddekany problem is resolved.

Comment: Kindly self answer this question so that others may benefit. Coincidentally it improves the struts2 tag answer rate ;)

Answer (score 0):

Define a custom transform method, such as the following:

```
public static void process(
ServletContext context, String template,
Map values, Writer writer) throws IOException,
TemplateException
 {
 Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
 cfg.setDirectoryForTemplateLoading(new
 File(context.getRealPath("/templates")));
 cfg.setObjectWrapper(new DefaultObjectWrapper());

 BeansWrapper wrapper = BeansWrapper.getDefaultInstance();

 TemplateHashModel staticModels = wrapper.getStaticModels();

 Template temp = cfg.getTemplate(template);

 temp.process(values, writer);

 writer.flush();
 }
```

**References**

- [FMPP Settings: Object Wrapping](http://fmpp.sourceforge.net/settings.html#objectWrapping)
- [Freemarker Source: BeansWrapperSingletonsTest.java](https://github.com/freemarker/freemarker-old/blob/master/src/test/java/freemarker/ext/beans/BeansWrapperSingletonsTest.java)